# Question about the degree of finite morphism of curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question about a definition in Hartshorne chapter II.6. Given a finite morphism $f:X\to Y$ of curves Hartshorne defines the degree of $f$ to be $[K(X):K(Y)]$. I don't understand though why $K(X)$ must be an extension of $K(Y)$ if $f$ is not assumed to be dominant. I would be grateful if someone could explain this to me!

Comment: A morphism of curves is dominant unless it factors through a point.

Comment: (Assuming the definition of curve requires irreducibility) If $f$ is nonconstant it must be dominant - it takes the generic point to the generic point.

Comment: Thanks! Hartshorne proves this in the proposition just before but there he assumes X is complete. I see now why it remains true for any curves though. //Ville